# Get document collections in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

this is my firebase database

```
- conversations (collection)
-- xxx (document)
--- users (collection)
---- xxx (document)
```

I want to list all the conversations and its users

```
this.db.collection('conversations').get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.collection('users').get())
    });
});
```

I´m getting doc.collection is not a function

update: this is what I have after getting the id and making a new query. now the question is. is this performant?

```
    this.db.collection('conversations').get().then(conversationsQuerySnapshot => {
        conversationsQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            this.db.collection('conversations').doc(doc.id).collection('users').get().then(usersQuerySnapshot => {
                usersQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    console.table(doc.data());
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: "Is this performant" is a very vague question.  You should benchmark the solution under the expected use cases and determine for yourself if it meets your performance needs.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `doc.ref.collection('users')`, since you need go get from the `DocumentSnapshot` to its `DocumentReference` through [`doc.ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#ref).

Note that I find it easiest to spot such mistakes by simply following the types. Your `querySnapshot` is a `QuerySnapshot`, which means that your `doc` is a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. Since [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) doesn't have a `collection` method, it's easier to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you would call it: db.collection('conversations').doc({docID}).collection('users')

Your current query is set up to look through every conversation and then get every user in each of those. Plus the second part (getting the users) has no base document to pull from, which is why you're seeing an error.

I recommend watching this [video](https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI)

Comment: hmmmm but I don´t know the {docID} is a list of conversations.  do I have to iterate over all documents in a collection. get the ID and then do the same but with the doc.id? not sure how to do it though

Comment: if you don't have the docID then what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: list all the conversations and all its users

Comment: you want to list every user in every conversation? Hopefully that's not a repeated call. In that case you can get the documentId of the given conversation with something like ((doc){
  let docID = doc.documentReference.documentID;
  //then do the:
  db.collection('conversations').doc(docID).collection('users')
})

Comment: You may want to format this in an async/await format rather than promise/callback. It's a bit easier to follow. Also, the code I provided is pseudocode and should be cross referenced with the documentation for specific javascript syntax.

Comment: Whoops, even that format I mention is wrong, not doc.docRef... the doc *is* a document reference and should contain the document ID you're going to need to do a query on the current document's collection of users. Just a quick thought on noSQL formatting, unless you're anticipating a LOT of users in each conversation you may want to store the users in a map within the conversation rather than a separate collection.  That would save you the need to do a second query on each conversation and cut down on your reads.

Comment: good point. only two users per conversation. but the messages list will be a different story. do you recommend a map for messages or a separate collection?

Comment: depends on how long you expect conversations to be... You could do a document for a cluster of messages and kind of parse through the information on each page. There is a firestore tutorial that does exactly this using Angular (I think that's what it's for). Though, you'd need to store a timestamp for each message with that tactic. You can store 20k fields or 1mb of data in each doc so this is more of a judgement call. The easiest route is using a doc for each message.